# Why doesn't php script print results to log when initiated via cron?

Tags: php, cron

crontab:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php  > /tmp/log/cron-$(date "+%F_%T").log 2>&1
```

When run manually this produces the expected log file:

```
$ php /path/to/script.php > /tmp/log/cron-$(date "+%F_%T").log
...
$ ls /tmp/log/
cron-2014-12-17_20:04:17.log
```

But when it's run from the cron, there is no record of the script running saved to a log file.

What am I missing?

**Update**

Alright, it appears to be a permission issue. If I create a log file and chmod 777 the cron will write to this file. But a cron will not write to a newly created date file. How can I allow this?

```
# This works, but does not allow dynamic dates
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php  > /tmp/log/cron.log 2>&1

# This does not work
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php  > /tmp/log/cron-$(date "+%F_%T").log 2>&1
```

`/tmp/log` is owned by `apache`, but the cron is initiated as `root`.

What do you recommend?

Comment: What user is running the crontab and is `$HOME` defined when using cron?

Comment: Are you aware that the value of $HOME is different for different users?

Comment: Also - for similar reasons - it's wise to include the full path to the php binary when invoking it via cron

Comment: Why run it as root? All users can maintain their own crontab

Comment: Even if `$HOME` is defined for `root`, it is probably not where you expect it to be and you should not be writing things there.

Comment: Alright, I revised everything to log to `/tmp/log/` to isolate any user issues. But the result is the same. Editing question to reflect fixed directory.

Answer (score 0):

run 
$which php
to figure out where your php is installed. Then check to see if root has it in the path.

you can just install it as your own crontab using 
$crontab -e

that's much better than running as root for many reasons, the least of which is that if your script has a vulernability it will have less access as you than as root.

Comment: Looks like you were answering as I was updating the question. No more user variable, and no more php path to be concerned about. Yet problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the ampersand?  You can redirect the output to the log with just the > operator.  My guess is the & sends the process to the background, and then there is nothing for the > operator to redirect to your log.

Comment: I removed the ampersand, waited a minute, and still no luck.  `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php > /tmp/log/process-$(date "+%F_%T").log` ... I also reran it manually and it spawned another `.log` file instantly.